# COM constructor throwing InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, .net, exception, com

I'd like to declare a managed class (built in C#/.NET) in an IDL file, but when I add a coclass for it I later get an InvalidCastException right as the constructor finishes and is returning.  (Unable to cast object 'MyThing' to type 'MyThingClass'.)

So in my test app (also C#/.NET) after registering the tlb it understands enough to call into the real constructor.  I can debug into to it even.  Everything works great until it has to return out of the constructor.

I thought about trying importlib to pull the DLL into the IDL, but I need the tlb before the build (chicken or egg issue).

Googling the issue just turns up simple casting problems.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at any of these questions http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=idl+c%23

Comment: Perhaps providing an example might get some more people answering>

Comment: Why are you creating the IDL manually instead of using Tlbexp/Regasm? And if both server and client are written in managed code, why are you using COM at all?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, we create a COM interface, then make sure that the class implements the interface. Not all .NET classes are understandable by VB6 and this has been a problem from the beginning. There are 2 books on the subject that I know well enough to recommend reading:
[.NET 2.0 Interoperability Recipes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590596692) and
[Professional Visual Basic Interoperability](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0000B0T0Q).

The 2nd book is much older and covers .NET 1, but still has some useful points to make.

My guess, based on what you've mentioned is that you're returning a class that VB (ok, this could be VC++, or something else) can't figure out.